# reactor thread pool dispatcher

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I went through reactor documentation, but I am unclear on how I can have some control over how many events are being dispatched at any given time. What I would like to do is dispatch a bunch of events, enough to keep some consumers busy, but then have some way of knowing I have enough consumers working at the moment so I shouldn't dispatch any more events. I was thinking if I set the dispatcher to use Threadpool then at some point it will not allocate any more threads and possibly throw a rejection exception. This way I can keep dispatching events until I receive a thread rejection exception.

Is there some way to do this or am I using reactor in a way that it's not supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep backlog size to zero, that way it will do what you are looking for!